# rootViewController property does not work on iOS 5 project with xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.2

Hi I just started experimenting on iOS 5. I created a project without storyboard and trying to add views programmatically (no use of interface builder at all). I have following code but rootViewController property of the window does not seem to work. I did NSLog on `self.tabController` and it shows me value(not null) but on the other side when after `self.window.rootViewController = self.tabController`, i output `self.window.rootViewController` it gives me null in console.

I have been struggling with this issue for a long time now. Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my `didFinishLaunching` method:

```
self.dataSource = [[[ADJWebDataSource alloc] init] autorelease];

ADJBrowseListingsViewController *browseListingsVC = [[ADJBrowseListingsViewController alloc] init];

ADJSecondViewController *secondVC = [[ADJSecondViewController alloc] init];
tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];   
tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browseListingsVC];    
NSMutableArray* viewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:2];

[viewControllers addObject:browseListingsVC];
[viewControllers addObject:secondVC];

[navController release];
[browseListingsVC release];
[secondVC release];

tabBarController.viewControllers = viewControllers;  
[viewControllers release]; 
browseListingsVC.dataSource = self.dataSource;   
NSLog(@"controller %@", self.tabBarController);   
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;   
NSLog(@"controller1 %@", self.window.rootViewController);
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Thanks
Vik

Comment: Do you have ARC enabled?

Comment: hey Wayne. No I don't. I am using retain and release methods.

Comment: Where did you create self.window? Are you sure self.window isn't nil?

Comment: Hey Firoze. Thanks for the reply. I have reference to Window in header file saying UIWindow *window and added property saying @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window; Synthesized it in implementation file as: @synthesize window. Is there anything else that I need to do in iOS5? coz thats all what i used to do in iOS4. Any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out with the help of Firoze. Actually, I had to allocate and initialize self.window programmatically. I was confused as I never had to do that in iOS 4 or earlier. But then I just realized prior to iOS5, every project has a MainWindow.xib which had self.window allocated and initialized, now if I am not using storyboard in iOS5, there is no .xib file, I needed to allocate and initialize it myself in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of Firoze. Actually, I had to allocate and initialize self.window programmatically. I was confused as I never had to do that in iOS 4 or earlier. But then I just realized prior to iOS5, every project has a MainWindow.xib which had self.window allocated and initialized, now if I am not using storyboard in iOS5, there is no .xib file, I needed to allocate and initialize it myself in the code

Answer (score 1):

When you are using story board, why are you still creating objects for view controllers?
You can directly prepare the flow of your views in story board, add necessary segues etc.
If your view controller is floating (without any segues), you have to use the method "instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier" in story board class.

For a view controller if you want to add navigation in story board, select the view controller, go to menu "Editor"->"Embed in" and select navigation controller. It will add navigation controller to your view controller.

Comment: hey Satyam, thanks for the reply. As I told you in my post, I am not using storyboard. I created this project without the support of storyboard.

Comment: When you are using iOS5, you can fully utilize the power of its features which is pretty easy.Anyway, did you create tab view controller?

Comment: I did created tabBar controller as following:  tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init]; (whole code is mentioned in main post)   Again the problem with storyboard is its not supported on iOS versions prior to iOS 5. Also, I am assuming it would be a good learning to know what exactly is going on if I don't use Storyboard and try to do it programmatically